# Timed out compiling Play 2.x - Java app (15 minutes) | Heroku and Play Framework

Tags: java, git, heroku, playframework, timeout

I'm tryingo to deploy my app done in Play Framework 2.2.2 to Heroku using "git push heroku master".
In my app directory are all the project files and directories created using play.
-.idea
-.idea_modules
-.settings
-app
-conf
-logs
-project
-public
-target
-test
-web
-build.sbt

This is what i get:

```
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-safari-driver;2.32.0
.
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...

 !     Timed out compiling Play 2.x - Java app (15 minutes)
 !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit

To git@heroku.com:warm-escarpment-8855.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:warm-escarpment-8855.git'
```

I also don't know how to use .slugignore, where to place it, witch files are important or not.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you can include .slugignore file to root of your app directory, where you probably have your gitignore file.. to make .slugignore, Just copy and change the extension of .gitignore.. You can add files like psd,pdf or images, directories to exclude it or counting it out from slug creation.

Comment: I posted this question on Heroku support area, and it seems like Play 2 builds tend to be slow, particularly on first push. Subsequent builds are incremental and shouldn't need an extended compile timeout. So they just extended my build time. Problem Solved!!!

Answer (score 1):

We used to have this exact problem. The solution is [sbt-heroku](https://github.com/heroku/sbt-heroku). Our builds went from 12 minutes, with an 60% chance of failure, to < 2 minutes, with 100% success.

No more slow builds! No more failed deployments!